# MKMapSnapshotter completion handler never works

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapsnapshotter

I've written this method to get the `UIImage` from the `MKMapSnapshotter`:

```
- (void)createSnapshot:(void (^)(UIImage *))image withOptions:(MKMapSnapshotOptions *)options
{
    MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc]initWithOptions:options];
    [snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error){
        image(snapshot.image);
    }];
}
```

Although everything works with iPhone OS9 the handler never gets called on my iPad OS 8.4.1

The maps are also not working correctly on the iPad. If somebody zooms in, the map is not loading further. Is there a problem with the mapkit???